# How can I submit an fql query using Facebook graph api with only a Facebook appId but without a user signing in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to use the new graph api for using FQL (the old api used https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22facebook.com%22), 
but it looks like I need an access token to use the new api ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.getStats/).

Is there a way to get statistics on a link without having a user logging in (a functionality like the old api)? Can this be done using only a Facebook appId?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call this url and parse the json response (obviously replacing the google.com with your page):

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://google.com

This url doesn't not require any kind of access token.

Comment: Thanks.
This works but the old api had more data (like count, share count, comment count and click count - https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?
query=select%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/%22)

Do you now if I can use this url with the Facebook batch api without an access token? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/

Comment: You can access the query without the token.  I remember this url bringing back that same info (like count, share count, comment count, etc) also, so try experimenting with different urls.